# Why is this insert code inserting data twice on button clicks?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2005, telerik, asp.net-3.5

The following code inserts same data two time in database table, but I want it to insert only one item when button is clicked.

What is the problem in this code?

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If RadUpload1.UploadedFiles.Count >= 0 Then
        Dim file As UploadedFile = RadUpload1.UploadedFiles(0)
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters("photo").DefaultValue = "./upload/" & file.GetName()
        'SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters("name").DefaultValue = TextBox1.Text
        SqlDataSource1.Insert()
        ListView1.DataBind()
    End If
    'UpdateProgressContext()
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you check if you are not declaring the same event two times? Check in page if the event is declared there.

Comment: the above was working fine but it inserts two record instead of single record on button click

Comment: try to use this:  if(Page.IsPostBack ){ ... your code here...}

Comment: what is the use of  if(Page.IsPostBack ), its not working ...

Comment: It Inserts two recoreds, because it is running two times. Check where you are declaring the event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be using both `OnClick="Button1_Click"` in your markup and `Handles Button1.Click` in your procedure.
Try removing one of them.